# Can't execute tasks in certain sequence in GULP

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I want to execute TASK `cssmin` after `scss`, but isn't working in this case.

If folder destination is not empty and .css files already compiled with separate task 'scss' then it works. But if folder is empty  then `cssmin` operates in idle and not create min file. Сan you help me?

Log in console:

```
[08:38:54] Starting 'scss'...
[08:38:54] Finished 'scss' after 13 ms
[08:38:54] Starting 'cssmin'...
[08:38:54] Finished 'cssmin' after 3.56 ms
```

My gulp tasks:

```
> gulp.task('scss' , function(){
>     gulp.src('app/scss/*.scss')
>         .pipe(scss())
>         .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
>         .pipe(bsync.stream()); });
> 
> gulp.task('cssmin' , ['scss'] , function () {
>     gulp.src('app/css/libs.css')
>         .pipe(cssnano())
>         .pipe(rename({
>             suffix: '-min'
>         }))
>         .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))});
```

Comment: I solved my problem through adding 'return' before function

Comment: grammar, formatting.

If you have found a solution, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem through adding 'return' before function